# difference between times in a file

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file in this format

```
02:20:25
02:21:00
02:22:54
02:23:28 
02:29:30 
....
```

I need to compute the difference in time between two successive lines. Is there a way to do it in shell scripts / awk ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simplistic way would be to convert each line to seconds, then subtract the previous line from the current line. Easy in awk. If that is actually what you want, then here is a possibility:

```
awk -f: '{\
  seconds = $1*60*60 + $2*60 + $3; \
  print seconds-prev_seconds; \
  prev_seconds=seconds;\
}' file.dat
```

This leaves the first difference as silly, but that is easily remedied by defaulting to the same value. It also does not convert back to differences in hours, minutes, seconds, but I don't know if you need that.

But to fix the first line, just say

```
awk -f: '{\
  seconds = $1*60*60 + $2*60 + $3; \
  if (prev_seconds == 0) prev_seconds = seconds; \
  print seconds-prev_seconds; \
  prev_seconds=seconds;\
}' file.dat
```

Now the first difference is 0, which is still weird but not as bad.

Comment: Be aware you'll get a large negative value each time you have two log lines which are either side of midnight.  Solutions vary depending on required accuracy.  You might just detect the negative value and suppress the spike, emitting zero for that step (losing the true gap size), or attempt to fix the calculation assuming it means one day boundary has been passed (and not several).

Comment: @neillb: good point. hard to say what the correct solution would be though without knowing where the data come from.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the awk 1 liner to get the time difference between 2 lines for input as above:

```
awk 'BEGIN{prevDt=0;} {gsub(/:/, " ", $1); dt=mktime("2011 01 01 " $1); print "Diff: " (dt-prevDt); prevDt=dt;}'
```

#### OUTPUT (for the input file as above)

```
Diff: 1293866425
Diff: 35
Diff: 114
Diff: 34
Diff: 362
```